# How can I build .a files with ffmpeg?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, ndk-build

I followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/ejoker88/FFmpeg-3.4-Android/wiki/Tutorial-:-FFmpeg-3.4-for-Android) and build ffmpeg.

But, it only build .so files and include folder.

I want to build .a files. My build [files.](https://github.com/ejoker88/FFmpeg-3.4-Android?files=1)

How can I build .a files with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial you followed had you use `--disable-static` which disables the creation of static libraries. Remove it and re-compile.

You only need to add `--enable-static` if you also include `--enable-shared`: this combination will provide both static and shared libraries. Without `--enable-shared` the static libraries will be created by default.

```
Options                                         Resulting libraries
./configure                                     static
./configure --enable-static                     static
./configure --enable-shared                     shared
./configure --enable-shared --enable-static     shared and static
```

Comment: I removed this `--disable-static` . but, it not done.

Comment: Give a  answer for  
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61004867/when-i-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-it-does-not-create-so-and-a-files-for-libavresamp

Answer (score 0):

Remove `--disable-static` and add `--enable-static`.