# When I build ffmpeg with ndk it does not create .so and .a files for libavresample and libpostproc

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

When I build ndk with ffmpeg it does not create .so and .a files for  libavresample and libpostproc .

I build ffmpeg with this [files.](https://github.com/ejoker88/FFmpeg-3.4-Android?files=1)

But , it does not create .so and .a files for  libavresample and libpostproc .

[image]
[image]

How can I build .so and .a files for  libavresample and libpostproc ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Do you really need libavresample and libpostproc?

I doubt it.

- *libavresample* - a deprecated alternative to the native libswresample, an audio resampling library. It is **not** enabled by default. If you want it then add the `--enable-avresample` configure option, but I advise against it unless you know for sure you need it.
- *libpostproc* - a legacy, almost forgotten library used for video post processing back when video was crappy looking. Required for the unfortunately named [pp filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pp) (which I've never seen anyone use). To enable this almost useless library you need to include the `--enable-gpl` configure option. **However, this will change the FFmpeg license from LGPL to GPL**, so be aware of the implications of this if you intend on distributing anything from FFmpeg.

Comment: My last question give a answer for this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61024056/how-can-i-build-x264-and-fdk-aac-for-android-with-ndk

Comment: @PradeepSimba Unfortunately I can't answer that one because I have no Android experience. You will have to compile or install x264 and fdk-aac before ffmpeg.

Comment: give a answer   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61037455/undefined-reference-to-function-in-c-with-ffmpeg

Comment: @PradeepSimba Can't help there either. Contact the author of that code.